# ASP.Net - Error mandar mail System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientException: El buzón de correo no está disponible

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp

Hola estoy tratando de mandar un mail desde `ASP.NET` este es mi metodo

```js
public ActionResult BolsaDeTrabajoContacto(string email_, string body, string nombre, string subject, HttpPostedFileBase files) {
  using(DBEnt db = new DBEnt()) {

    var cont = db.Contactos.ToList < Contactos > ().Where(u => u.tipo.Equals("mitipo")).FirstOrDefault();
    var dest = cont.destino;
    string path = "~/Content/Upload/";
    try {


      MailAddress from = new MailAddress("pw.fs@pw.fs.com.mx");
      MailAddress to = new MailAddress("pushpoped@gmail.com");
      MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, to);


      mail.From = new MailAddress("pw.fs@financierasumate.com.mx");
      //mail.To.Add("pushpoped@gmail.com");
      mail.Subject = nombre + " : " + subject;
      mail.Body = body;
      SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("pw.fs.com.mx", 587);

      SmtpServer.Port = 587;
      SmtpServer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("pw.fs@gmail.com.mx", "mi.pass.sh");
      SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
      SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

      if (files != null) {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(path));

        string filePath = Server.MapPath(path + files.FileName);
        files.SaveAs(filePath);

        mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(Server.MapPath(path + files.FileName)));

      }



      ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(
        object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) {
        return true;
      };

      SmtpServer.Send(mail);
      //MessageBox.Show("mail Send");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      //MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
      return Json("Error mandar mail " + ex.ToString());
    }

    return Json("Exito mandando mail ");
  }


}
```

este es mi error:

> "Error mandar mail System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientException: El buzón de correo no está disponible. La respuesta del servidor fue: SMTP AUTH is required for message submission on port 587\r\n   en System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, Boolean allowUnicode, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception)\r\n   en System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)\r\n   en WebFS.Controllers.HomeController.BolsaDeTrabajoContacto(String email_, String body, String nombre, String subject, HttpPostedFileBase files) en C:\Users\EjeDesarrolloCS-162\source\repos\WebFS\WebFS\Controllers\HomeController.cs:línea 555"

Comment: Por lo visto no esta reconociendo las credenciales, lo que no entiendo es porque usas `pw.fs.com.mx` para el smtp junto a un mail de `gmail`, el smtp de gmail es `smtp.gmail.com`

Answer (score 0):

Yo para enviar por gmail, uso lo siguiente:

```
public static bool enviarEmailNormal(string destino, string asunto, string mensaje, bool esHtml, string cc = "", string bcc = "")
{
    bool resultado = false;

    try
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(destino) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(asunto) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mensaje))
        {
            var desde = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpUsuario"].ToString(), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpNombreOrigen"].ToString());
            var para = new MailAddress(destino);
            string clave = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpClave"].ToString();

            var smtp = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpServidor"].ToString(),
                Port = 587,
                EnableSsl = true,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(desde.Address, clave),
                Timeout = 20000
            };

            var message = new MailMessage();
            message.From = desde;
            message.To.Add(para);
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cc))
            {
                var copia = new MailAddress(cc);
                message.To.Add(cc);
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(bcc))
            {
                var copia = new MailAddress(bcc);
                message.Bcc.Add(bcc);
            }
            message.Subject = asunto;
            message.IsBodyHtml = esHtml;
            message.Body = mensaje;

            smtp.Send(message);
            resultado = true;
        }
        else
            resultado = false;
    }
    catch (Exception fallo)
    {
        resultado = false;
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

En el Web.config tengo definidas las siguientes variables

```
<add key="smtpServidor" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
<add key="smtpUsuario" value="tusuario@gmail.com" />
<add key="smtpClave" value="tuclave" />
<add key="smtpNombreOrigen" value="NombreRemitente" />
```